# Django SimpleListFilter max record

Tags: python, django, filter, max, django-queryset

two models:

```
project(models.Model):
name = models.CharField...

yearreport((models.Model)
year = [2014,2015,2016] #example
project = models.ForeignKey(project)

""" examples:
Project A has reports for 2014
Project B has reports for 2014,2015
Project C has reports for 2014,2015,2016
"""
```

I now want to build a SimpleListFilter for the Django Admin,
which filters for the highest/most recent report a project has.
For example if I filter for 2015 only project B should show.
(With a normal filter, this request would also show C, I don't want that)

I tried some funky things...

```
queryset.filter(Max('yearreport__year')==self.value()))
```

but I just lost in not knowing the syntax..

Pleas end my guessing game :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think sth like this should work:

```
queryset.annotate(
    max_year=Max('yearreport__year')
).filter(
    yearreport__year=max_year
)
```